# Calling a asynchronous function inside getDerivedStateFromProps in React

Tags: reactjs

I need to update a table when a state got updated. So I tried to call a function update inside getDerivedStateFromProps but it seems like I can't use 'this' inside getDerivedStateFromProps. Is there any way to do that? Thank in advance.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    if(props.newValue != state.newValue) {
      this.updateTable();
      return {
        newValue : props.newValue 
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: What does updateTable() do?

Comment: like you click a number of pagination, calling API and update state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateTable` is a `sideEffect` function that need not be present in `getDerivedStateFromProps`

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is intentionally written as a static function so that you cannot call class instance functions from it

In order to handle sideEffect you must perform them in componentDidUpdate function

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(this.props.newValue != prevProps.newValue) {
      this.updateTable();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't think this is work. props were changed but componentDidUpdate didn't be called

Comment: @Riya componentDidUpdate will be called if your props changed unless you implement shouldComponentUpdate to stop the update from happening

Comment: @Khatri I have a parent component and a child component, then I passing a state from parent component to child component by click. console shows that props were changed, but componentDidUpdate didn't work

Comment: could you please show more of your component or create a reproducible demo on codesandbox

Comment: Welcome, I am happy that you figured the issue on your own too